# I would like to cite different authors during my thesis and if I click on the name can bring me to the Bibliography at the end. How can I do it?

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, citing

How can I generate my bibliography in this way ? I would like to cite the author during my writing and if I click on the bibliography name can bring me to the biblography at the  end

Comment: use the standard LaTeX citation methods. I bet the tutorial you've been reading to introduce you to LaTeX mentions these! It's a pretty important feature.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you don't know where to start, maybe check https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management

Comment: @MarcusMüller your link explains how to cite, but not how to link the citation to the bibliography. The answer is using the `hyperref` package. That is the package that... well... links stuff. Also, you should put `\useapackage{hyperref}` last in the preamble.

Comment: Aso, @anzhela, we forgot to welcome you! So hi and welcome to TeX.SX! If our comments are not helpful, it would help focus us if you add a small Minimal Working Example (MWE): a small file that recreates your problem starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. We could run that on our end and see what your problem really is :)